# mobile application twebbrowser post method

Tags: post, firemonkey, twebbrowser

Is there any simple way to open page in mobile application using twebbrowser
containing two text parameters - post method (it can't be get it must be post).

I know I can use idhttp to post parameters but i don't know how to open page in twebbroser with posted parameters ?

Please maybe someone will explain it to me as simply as it can be done ;)

Comment: Not TWebBrowser, which is an ActiveX control, not for use in FireMonkey.

Comment: Open a web page that contains Javascript and have the Javascript do the POST.